# How to store timestamp value upto only 3 millisecond digit in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have to store upto 3 millisecond digit in timestamp column.
I have two fixed column in each tables: createdDate,LastmodifiedDate.
While inserting data value of CreatedDate/LastmodifiedDate:

```
now() at time zone 'utc'
```

But it is storing 5 digit of millisecond. 
I would like to store only 3 fractional digit of millisecond.
let me suggest which type of datatype is storing only 3 fractional digit of millisecond.
let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres allows you to specify precision(0 to 6) while casting to `TIMESTAMP`

See [**Docs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

So, you could do

```
select (now() at time zone 'utc') :: timestamp(3)
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fd14386bb223f540ae9ee28d66992df5)